# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: with two sibling Angular components

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material, panel, siblings

I'm using Angular Material expansion-panel with Flex-Layout and I would like to split my two expansion-panel into two different components.

I realized a [StackBlitz1 HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-expansion-panel-with-flex-layout-2?file=app%2Fexpansion-overview-example.html) using both expansion-panel in the same component.
On the other hand, in my second [StackBlitz2 HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-expansion-panel-with-flex-layout-3-component?file=app%2Fexpansion-overview-example.html), I split these two expansion-panels in two different components, but an error occurs.
The error ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError appears and it comes from my function "changeExpansionPanelState ()" in the HTML file of my two components.

```
<mat-expansion-panel (opened)="changeExpansionPanelState()"
                     (closed)="changeExpansionPanelState()">
  ...
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

If someone has a solution to be able to do the same thing as my StackBlitz1 with two components, I'm interested.

DEMO:

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-expansion-panel-with-flex-layout-3-component-yj8ui6

Comment: Read this: https://blog.angularindepth.com/a-gentle-introduction-into-change-detection-in-angular-33f9ffff6f10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally changed my method and found a simpler solution to my problem without going through service, here is the result:

[**StackBlitz HERE**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-expansion-panel-with-flex-layout-4-component)

Answer (score 1):

Chellappan's answer is correct, the reason why is below...

Your HTML uses the `panelOpenState` boolean component variables to control your view... you instantiate these variables with no value when the component is initialized.

```
  panelOpenState1: boolean;
  panelOpenState2: boolean;
```

You then set the value to these component variables **after the view is rendered** via the service subscription...

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.panelState.panelOpenState1$.subscribe(panelOpenState1 => this.panelOpenState1 = panelOpenState1);
    this.panelState.panelOpenState2$.subscribe(panelOpenState2 => this.panelOpenState2 = panelOpenState2);
  }
```

So when the view is rendered, for `[ngClass]="{'flex': panelOpenState2}"` the `panelOpenState2` component variable is `undefined` at this point... but then the subscriptions are created which takes the previous checked value of `undefined` and replaces it with the observable boolean value.

```
Previous value: 'flex: undefined'. Current value: 'flex: true'
```

---

> The key to avoiding this is to do one of the following...

Instantiate your component variables with a value.

```
export class FirstPanelComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  panelOpenState1: boolean = true;
  panelOpenState2: boolean = false;
```

Or create your subscriptions when the component is initialized... **before** your view is rendered so the component variables are not `undefined` when the view needs them.

```
  ngOnInit(){
    this.panelState.panelOpenState1$.subscribe(panelOpenState1 => this.panelOpenState1 = panelOpenState1);
    this.panelState.panelOpenState2$.subscribe(panelOpenState2 => this.panelOpenState2 = panelOpenState2);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // this.panelState.panelOpenState1$.subscribe(panelOpenState1 => this.panelOpenState1 = panelOpenState1);
    // this.panelState.panelOpenState2$.subscribe(panelOpenState2 => this.panelOpenState2 = panelOpenState2);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will change that.